# Inequality operator in where clause not working in firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, geofirex

I want to track users present within a radius in realtime. I have a firestore collection documents that have the field `userId` different than my userId.

This is the code

```
   this.watch = Plugins.Geolocation.watchPosition(
        { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 5000 },
        (geoPosition) => {
          if (geoPosition) {
            console.log(geoPosition);
            const field = "position";
            const center = this.geo.point(
              geoPosition.coords.latitude,
              geoPosition.coords.longitude
            );
            const usersRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('users');
            const nearbyusers = usersRef.where('userId', '!=', this.uid).orderBy('userId');
        
            const position = this.geo.point(
              geoPosition.coords.latitude,
              geoPosition.coords.longitude
            );
            usersRef.doc(this.uid).set({ position }, { merge: true });
            this.points = this.radius.pipe(
              switchMap((r) => {
                return this.geo.query(nearbyusers).within(center, r, field, {log: true});
              }),
              shareReplay(1)
            );
          }
        }
      );
```

In my users collection I have two documents. but after running this code I don't get nothing.
No error.

Comment: Queries with a != clause are not supported. In this case, split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE I tried it but not working neither.

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE you should probably write an answer base on your comment.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Why would I do that ? I just make a google search, I think that it don't deserve any points.

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE Even if you "just" made a Google search, you've spent some time searching for a solution to the OP's question and writing a comment with the solution. Therefore I think that you deserve the points! Also, writing an answer will make it clear to future readers what is the solution (instead of reading the comments). Since the question is titled "**Inequality operator in where clause** not working in Firestore" there is a chance that a future search lead to the question.

Comment: @Midou Which version of the JS SDK are you using?

Comment: @Renaud I am using the latest version of firebase Version 7.21.0 which supports inequality operator `!=` . See  [Firebase JavaScript Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7210_-_september_17_2020)

Comment: @Midou yes, it should work.  Are you sure `this.uid` value is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try doing this :

> Queries with a != clause are not supported. In this case, split the
> query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example,
> although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported,
> you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the
> clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age",
> ">", 30) [Read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)

So for you it'll be something like this :

```
...
const nearbyusers = usersRef
                    .where('userId', '<', this.uid)
                    .where('userId', '>', this.uid)
                    .orderBy('userId')
...
```